# How to pass a vector to a function?

Tags: c++, function, vector

I'm trying to send a vector as an argument to a function and i can't figure out how to make it work. Tried a bunch of different ways but they all give different error messages.
I only include part of the code, since it's only this part that doesn't work.
(the vector "random" is filled with random, but sorted, values between 0 and 200)

Updated the code:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <ctime>        
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>       

using namespace std;

int binarySearch(int first, int last, int search4, vector<int>& random);

int main()
{
    vector<int> random(100);

    int search4, found;
    int first = 0;
    int last = 99;

    found = binarySearch(first, last, search4, random);

    system("pause");    
    return(0);      
}

int binarySearch(int first, int last, int search4, vector<int>& random)
{
    do
    {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;  
        if (search4 > random[mid]) 
            first = mid + 1;  
        else if (search4 < random[mid]) 
            last = mid - 1; 
        else
            return mid;     
    } while (first <= last); 

    return -(first + 1);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Please post errors.

Comment: On the updates code: The parameters first and last are **values** from the vector, not indexes. You also never set a value to search for (search4)!

Comment: Using `using namespace std;` is a bad idea.  [Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: please note that the expected error in the question has been corrected.. making it meaningless..

Answer (score 137, accepted):

It depends on if you want to pass the `vector` as a reference or as a pointer (I am disregarding the option of passing it by value as clearly undesirable).

As a reference:

```
int binarySearch(int first, int last, int search4, vector<int>& random);

vector<int> random(100);
// ...
found = binarySearch(first, last, search4, random);
```

As a pointer:

```
int binarySearch(int first, int last, int search4, vector<int>* random);

vector<int> random(100);
// ...
found = binarySearch(first, last, search4, &random);
```

Inside `binarySearch`, you will need to use `.` or `->` to access the members of `random` correspondingly.

**Issues with your current code**

1. `binarySearch` expects a `vector<int>*`, but you pass in a `vector<int>` (missing a `&` before `random`)
2. You do not dereference the pointer inside `binarySearch` before using it (for example, `random[mid]` should be `(*random)[mid]`
3. You are missing `using namespace std;` after the `<include>`s
4. The values you assign to `first` and `last` are wrong (should be 0 and 99 instead of `random[0]` and `random[99]`

Comment: "The values you assign to first and last are wrong (should be 0 and 99 instead of random[0] and random[99]" - but i want "first" to be the first value in random and "last" to be the last one. I do not want them to be the values 0 and 99.

Comment: Joe: `first` and `last` are *indexes*, not values. You are confused as to what they represent.

Comment: Then how do i give `Last` the last value of the vector?

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, i see my misstake now. Thank you!

Comment: @Jon I have a small doubt after reading your second point, Why we can not dereference that pointer which collects the address of array when we pass it to a function.

Comment: Can you explain why "the option of passing it by value is clearly undesirable" ? If I just want to print the element in it , will it be faster ?

Comment: @lecaruyer: Briefly, passing by value means that the contents of the vector must be copy-constructible, and a copy of everything will actually be created. The effects of this could in practice range from negligible, to very problematic from a performance and/or resource point of view, to code that does not even compile. There's no reason to do it unless you really do want a second copy of the stuff.

Answer (score 8):

You'll have to pass the pointer to the vector, not the vector itself. Note the additional '&' here:

```
found = binarySearch(first, last, search4, &random);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in a pointer `*random` but you're using it like a reference `&random`

The pointer (what you have) says "This is the address in memory that contains the address of random"

The reference says "This is the address of random"

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you're tempted to pass a collection (or pointer or reference to one) to a function, ask yourself whether you couldn't pass a couple of iterators instead. Chances are that by doing so, you'll make your function more versatile (e.g., make it trivial to work with data in another type of container when/if needed).

In this case, of course, there's not much point since the standard library already has perfectly good binary searching, but when/if you write something that's not already there, being able to use it on different types of containers is often quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

```
found = binarySearch(first, last, search4, &random);
```

Notice the `&`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the argument as a reference but actually it's a pointer. Change `vector<int>*` to `vector<int>&`. And you should really set `search4` to something before using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `random` instead of `* random` your code not give any error